WordPress Plugin Activated but Not Visible in Gutenberg Blocks
npx @wordpress/create-block copyright-date-block --template @wordpress/create-block-tutorial-template
After successfully activating the plugin in the WordPress admin panel, I expected to see my custom block ("copyright-date-block") in the Gutenberg editor. However, upon searching for it in the Gutenberg blocks, I couldn't find it anywhere.
Can anyone guide me on how I can see my "copyright-date-block" in my WordPress Gutenberg editor? Are there any specific steps or settings I need to follow?
Steps Taken and Expected Outcome:
Plugin Creation: I used the npx @wordpress/create-block command to generate the plugin named "copyright-date-block" based on the tutorial template.
Plugin Activation: After successfully creating the plugin, I activated it in the WordPress admin panel under the "Plugins" section. I expected the activated plugin to be fully functional and visible in the Gutenberg editor.

Having the same issue, all I have done at this point is follow the tutorial on WordPress activated the plugin and not seeing it anywhere, not sure whats going on really irritating at this point as I've nto made any changes and just trying it out.

Took me a while but got it working downgrade the versions of the WordPress scripts:
package.json
@wordpress/scripts": "28.0.0" --> 27.9.0 

then delete node_modules folder, run npm install, then run npm build.
Src: https://community.localwp.com/t/block-plugin-development-using-create-block-package-issue/43192

This also solves my issue. Also taken me a while to figure it out or find this post. Btw, after downgrading you need to run npm run build or npm run start so that it shows up.
